# Unable to understand a folder which moves my location in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am at the folder wcw. I run

```
$pwd
/Users/cs/Coding-projects/wcw
$ls -lsa
total 0
0 drwxr-xr-x   5 M  staff   170B Apr  5 16:56 .
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 M  staff   102B Apr  4 11:25 ..
0 drwxr-xr-x  12 M  staff   408B Apr  5 16:56 .git
0 -rw-r--r--   1 M  staff     0B Apr  4 11:29 README
0 -rw-r--r--   1 M  staff     0B Apr  5 16:56 test
```

I want to go to the folder "test". I run

```
$cd test 
/Users/M/Documents/test
```

I run the following to see where I am now

```
$pwd
/Users/M/Documents/test
```

The folder test is not a symlink, as you can see from the above ls command.

**What is the folder test?**

How can it throw me to a random place?

Comment: `test` isn't a directory, it is an empty file. Your terminal output makes no sense. `cd test` should have failed, it shouldn't have printed anything. Care to provide a zip of the directory?

Also, what shell are you running?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, but IMO you should run fsck.

Comment: @freespace: I run Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your directory structure you are on an Apple system.
Apple HFS still supports forks and since the file test has 0 zero there maybe a fork which links somewhere else.

Comment: @Jaap: How can I edit that fork?